# Compute yhat for OLS Regression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have implemented a method to compute betas for OLS regression in python. Now, I would like to score my model using R^2. For my assignment, I am not allowed to use Python packages to do so, so would have to implement a method from scratch.

```
#load the data
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.linalg import inv
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
boston = load_boston()

# Set the X and y variables. 
X = boston.data
y = boston.target

#append ones to my X matrix. 
int = np.ones(shape=y.shape)[..., None]
X = np.concatenate((int, X), 1)

#compute betas. 
betas = inv(X.transpose().dot(X)).dot(X.transpose()).dot(y)

# extract the feature names of the boston data set and prepend the 
#intercept
names = np.insert(boston.feature_names, 0, 'INT')

# collect results into a DataFrame for pretty printing
results = pd.DataFrame({'coeffs':betas}, index=names)

#print the results
print(results)

            coeffs
INT      36.491103
CRIM     -0.107171
ZN        0.046395
INDUS     0.020860
CHAS      2.688561
NOX     -17.795759
RM        3.804752
AGE       0.000751
DIS      -1.475759
RAD       0.305655
TAX      -0.012329
PTRATIO  -0.953464
B         0.009393
LSTAT    -0.525467
```

Now, I would like to implement a R^2 to score my model on this data (or any other data). (see here: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

My issue is I am not entirely certain how to compute the numerator, SSE. In code it would look like this:

```
#numerator
sse = sum((Y - yhat ** 2)
```

Where Y are the boston house prices, and yhat are the predicted prices of these houses. However, how do I compute the term, `yhat`?

Comment: You do not square the yhat, you square the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yhat` is your estimate for a given observation.  You can obtain all of your estimates simultaneously using the [dot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) product via `X.dot(betas)`.

Your sum square of errors would be the following (note the correction to version you gave: you need to square the *difference*, i.e. square the errors):

```
y_hat = X.dot(betas)
errors = y - y_hat 
sse = (errors ** 2).sum()
```

Your total sum of squares:

```
tss = ((y - y.mean()) ** 2).sum()
```

And the resulting R-squared (coefficient of determination):

```
r2 = 1 - sse / tss
```

Also, I wouldn't use `int` as a variable name to avoid clobbering the built in [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function (just call it `ones` or `const` instead).

Comment: That was easier than expected, gotta up my math game for sure. Thank you!